# Display CKEditor's saved Data in user page

Tags: php, ckeditor

I have used ckeditor in textarea. The textarea submits data in php file and later saved in database.

Now I want to display the data (Render) with format. But when I display the saved data in a page, the stylesheet of those data won't applied because of my page uses different stylesheet.

```
     <div class="displayck reset-this">
    <?php
    /* THIS IS CK EDITOR DATA */
                $visible = $con->prepare("SELECT text FROM test WHERE id = 1");
                $visible->execute();
                $data = $visible->fetchColumn();
                echo $data;
    ?>
        </div>
```

How can I output the data with stylesheet formatting.